# How to optimize multer's performance?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have a node/express app. I parse a formData that contains an array of images with Multer. Once the images are parsed, they are uploaded to cloudinary. It works well.

I use the diskStorage method:

```js
const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });

router.post("/upload-images", upload.array("image"), (req, res) => {
//do stuff
}
```

It is convenient because my files are immediately available, and I don't have to parse a buffer afterwards. However, how does this diskStorage works exactly? Is it saving the images on the user's computer, or on the server? Are the images automatically deleted after a few minutes or do they stay here, eating up all the memory?

Is it best to use diskStorage or memoryStorage and why? How to optimize my server's performances?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you select the storage method? It's not shown here.

Comment: Usually if you're using a Cloudinary storage method plugin you are *not* also using these other ones, so that's irrelevant. Keep in mind questions like "How to optimize my server's performances?" are impossible to answer without a *measurable performance problem*.

Comment: Based on Multer's doc, I've just written var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' }) and assumed it was using diskStorage by default. If it is not the case, what does multer({ dest: 'uploads/' }) do exactly? Does it store the files somewhere, are are they just temporary data ready to be uploaded to cloudinary?

Comment: Normally it saves them on your system (or server's) local disk. If you want to use something else, like Cloudinary or Amazon S3, you must explicitly configure it to do so. The `memoryStorage` version is presumably for testing where you want to throw them out after the testing process is complete, not clutter up your drive with test uploads.

Comment: How to delete the files stored on the server once the cloudinary upload is complete then? It would be best to avoid having 10000+ files on my server.

Comment: Again, either you use the Cloudinary plugin *or* you use `diskStorage`. It is not a case of using both. You may think you're using Cloudinary but in fact are not. In any case these files should be easy to find, just look in the `uploads/` directory and see what's there.

Comment: Oo yes, a folder called "uploads" has been created with all the images. How can you automatically delete its content once the upload is complete? Yes, I am using cloudinary, the images are stored on my cloud.

Comment: Are you *sure* those images are being uploaded? I would move those images somewhere safe before presuming they can be deleted. You may have a mix of locally stored files and cloud-hosted files. There are storage plugins like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-storage-cloudinary) that you use in place of the others. Maybe you're doing something else? The `// do stuff` code is doing the upload or no?

Comment: Yes I'm sure they are uploaded. I receive an object with a secure url afterwards, and I can store this one in my database, so I can serve images through a cdn. I don't need the images in the folder uploads.

Comment: If you're doing the upload manually then you may need to clean up the local files as part of that upload process. I'd suggest using that storage plugin as it'll likely do it all for you, neatly.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll check it out!